# Capture IOS logs to a text file with an automated script

Tags: python, ios, appium

I am new to MAC world. The requirement is to capture ios logs to a file and grep it for a ip address. Using Appium and python2.7, is there any way to do it without launching xcode?

Is there any way to automate it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Have you checked out CocoaLumberjack? It's not Python but it's a super awesome way to capture logs.

Answer (score 0):

capture app log?
if so that is always automaticlly.
you do not need to launch xcode.
It's not about xcode, it's depend on that where the log files you submit,
and ways you logged

Answer (score 0):

Installed Apple configurator 2 on my mac.
ran command **/usr/local/bin/cfgutil syslog** on cammand line prompt to see the log.

Answer (score 0):

Install libimobiledevice. Run command idevicesyslog using python and capture the logs.

Comment: I am using `idevicesyslog` with ruby currently, and it displays the logs in the terminal as soon as I have a failure in my tests. Any idea how to write those logs to a file and save it? Like similar to `adb logcat -d > logs.txt`